# New and Edit Routes missing in Rails Resources routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In building a Rails API, I declared my routes file as:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      root 'budgets#index'
      resources :users do
        resources :budgets
      end
      post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
      post '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
      resources :budgets do
        resources :budget_totals
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, after running the `rails routes` command, I found that the "new" and "edit" routes are missing. How do I rectify this?

The relevant portion of the `rails routes` response is:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                          api_v1_root GET    /api/v1(.:format)                                                                        api/v1/budgets#index
                  api_v1_user_budgets GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/budgets(.:format)                                                 api/v1/budgets#index
                                      POST   /api/v1/users/:user_id/budgets(.:format)                                                 api/v1/budgets#create
                   api_v1_user_budget GET    /api/v1/users/:user_id/budgets/:id(.:format)                                             api/v1/budgets#show
                                      PATCH  /api/v1/users/:user_id/budgets/:id(.:format)                                             api/v1/budgets#update
                                      PUT    /api/v1/users/:user_id/budgets/:id(.:format)                                             api/v1/budgets#update
                                      DELETE /api/v1/users/:user_id/budgets/:id(.:format)                                             api/v1/budgets#destroy
                         api_v1_users GET    /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users#index
                                      POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users#create
                          api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users#show
                                      PATCH  /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users#update
                                      PUT    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users#update
                                      DELETE /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users#destroy
                         api_v1_login POST   /api/v1/login(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/sessions#create
                        api_v1_logout POST   /api/v1/logout(.:format)                                                                 api/v1/sessions#destroy
          api_v1_budget_budget_totals GET    /api/v1/budgets/:budget_id/budget_totals(.:format)                                       api/v1/budget_totals#index
                                      POST   /api/v1/budgets/:budget_id/budget_totals(.:format)                                       api/v1/budget_totals#create
           api_v1_budget_budget_total GET    /api/v1/budgets/:budget_id/budget_totals/:id(.:format)                                   api/v1/budget_totals#show
                                      PATCH  /api/v1/budgets/:budget_id/budget_totals/:id(.:format)                                   api/v1/budget_totals#update
                                      PUT    /api/v1/budgets/:budget_id/budget_totals/:id(.:format)                                   api/v1/budget_totals#update
                                      DELETE /api/v1/budgets/:budget_id/budget_totals/:id(.:format)                                   api/v1/budget_totals#destroy
                       api_v1_budgets GET    /api/v1/budgets(.:format)                                                                api/v1/budgets#index
                                      POST   /api/v1/budgets(.:format)                                                                api/v1/budgets#create
                        api_v1_budget GET    /api/v1/budgets/:id(.:format)                                                            api/v1/budgets#show
                                      PATCH  /api/v1/budgets/:id(.:format)                                                            api/v1/budgets#update
                                      PUT    /api/v1/budgets/:id(.:format)                                                            api/v1/budgets#update
                                      DELETE /api/v1/budgets/:id(.:format)                                                            api/v1/budgets#destroy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps using the `api_only` app? Those do not generate `New` and `Edit` routes.

Did you create your app with the `--api` switch,  such as: `rails new my-api --api`?  The `--api` argument tells Rails that you want an API application only.

See "[What Is Rails API?](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19832)" and "[Rails: Building a Ruby on Rails API-only app](https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2016/07/05/rails-5-api-only-app/)".

Comment: It was a surprise to me as well. You can still manually create `new` and `edit` routes. They're just not automatic. I guess the assumption is an API-only app would not have them.

Comment: @Genetic1989 if you wouldn't mind selecting this as the accepted answer that would be awesome. It will make it easier for other people with your same question to find the answer.